# When can we change integral and partial derivatives for improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function over $\mathbb{R}^2$. When can we interchange integrals and partial derivatives for improper integrals?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int _\mathbb{R} f(x,t)dx=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dx$$

I know the Leibniz rule works for proper integrals and the fact that we have a continuously differentiable function intuitively leads me to believe this is possible assuming that all the integrals are well defined (integral gives us a finite value for all slices and all slices of the partial derivative) although I am not sure what theorem justifies this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of results upon integrals depending on one parameter that are consequence of the well-known Dominated Convergence Theorem. In this case, you can change the integral with the derivative operator according with the following:

> Suppose that for some $t_{0} \in [a,b]$, the function $x \to f(x, t_{0})$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, that $\partial f / \partial t$ exists on $\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]$, and that there exist an integrable function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$
> \left \lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \right \rvert \leq g(x).
> $$
> Then the function
> $$
> F(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, t)\, dx
> $$
> is well defined and it is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and
> $$
> \frac{dF}{dt}(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x, t)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\,dx.
> $$

Let $t$ any point in $[a,b]$. If $\{t_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$ converging to $t$ with $t_{n} \neq t$, then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)=  \lim 
\frac{f(x, t_{n}) - f(x,t)}
{t_{n} - t}, \quad x \in \mathbf{R}.
$$
Therefore the function $x \mapsto (\partial f/\partial t)(x, t)$ is measurable.
Applying the mean value theorem we have that
$$
f(x,t) - f(x, t_{0}) = 
(t - t_{0}) 
\frac{\partial f}
{\partial t}(x, s_{1}).
$$
Therefore
$$
\lvert f(x,t) \rvert \leq
\lvert f(x, t_{0}) \rvert +
\lvert t - t_{0} \rvert g(x),
$$
which shows that the function $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is integrable for each $t$ in $[a,b]$. Hence, if $t_{n} \neq t$, then
$$
\frac{F(t_{n}) - F(t)}
{t_{n} - t} = 
\int
\frac{f(x, t_{n}) - f(x, t)}
{t_{n} - t}\, dx.
$$

Applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem we have
$$
F'(t) = \int
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\, dx.
$$